# How to apply custom CodeAccessSecurityAttribute to a Property?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I'm trying to implement a custom `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute`, as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class AuthoriseAttribute : System.Security.Permissions.CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    // custom security implementation
}
```

I want to restrict access to a property, e.g.:

```
public class Dashboard : Page
{
    [Authorise(SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public List<RedirectNameValueBo> ClientsContractExpiring
    {
        set
        {
            this.ctlClientContractExpiry.ItemList = value;
            this.ctlClientContractExpiry.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Error emitting 'Namespace.AuthoriseAttribute' attribute -- 'Security custom attribute attached to invalid parent.'
```

For the record, if I change the `AttributeUsage` to `AttributeTargets.Method`, and apply the attribute to a method it works fine, e.g.:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthoriseAttribute : System.Security.Permissions.CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    // custom security implementation
}

[Authorise(SecurityAction.Demand)]
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

What do I need to do to be able to apply this Custom Attribute to a Property?

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this problem too. Unfortunately CodeAccessSecurityAttribute and everything derived from it can not be applied to properties. But there is simple workaround: Apply that attribute to getter and/or setter of desired property - getters and setters are methods under the hood. I am giving you example in Visual Basic .NET, you should be able to translate it to C#.

```
'This does not work:
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="Administrator")>
Public Property IsEnabled As Boolean

'This works:
Private _isEnabled As Boolean
Public Property IsEnabled As Boolean
  <PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="Administrator")>
  Get
    Return _isEnabled
  End Get
  <PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="Administrator")>
  Set (value As Boolean)
    _isEnabled = value
  End Set
End Property
```